# Ready-made database for Neo4j

Tags: xml, database, neo4j, cypher

I need to run some tests on Neo4j performances with different sized databases.
I would like to know if there are some ready-made databases / Cypher CREATE queries I could use.
I tried a workaround: converting an XML databse into a CREATE quert with the XML to Cypher Converter by Nigel Small but I've not been able to make it work  (500 Internal Server Error).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've found Neo4j website hosts some example dataset to use [here](http://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/). The movie database works like a charm. I also downloaded the Musicbrainz database but it seems there must be something wrong with the archive: every time I try to extract it some errors are thrown (corrupted file or unsupported compression). I also tryed to repair it with no success. 
A database with millions of nodes is exactly what I was looking for!
Any idea how to solve this? Any other place I could find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a way to import my .xml into Neo4j.
I converted the .xml into a .csv and then I imported it following [this instructions](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of ready-made XML databases, but you can use the utility [xml2neo](https://github.com/moxious/xml2neo) to transform any XML document you want into a series of cypher statements prepped for neo4j.

At that point, you can then just import whatever XML you want into a neo4j database, and continue until you get the size that you want.  For example, you could easily pull any of millions of ATOM or RSS feeds that way.

Comment: This tool could be great but it seems to have some flaws. I tryed to use it with the sample.xml provided and it generated some cypher queries that threw syntax errors when used in Neo4j.

Comment: Post it as an issue along with a sample of your xml and it will get corrected

Answer (score 0):

It's not "ready-made" persay where it installs out of the box with a fully populated database, however I am getting more interested in Neo4j's spatial capabilities and am using the following as my base to start from.

http://www.lyonwj.com/mapping-the-worlds-airports-with-neo4j-spatial-and-openflights-part-1/

In this site, it provides the link to the dataset of worldwide airports (though it's a bit difficult to find at first, so the specific link to the dataset is below):

https://sourceforge.net/p/openflights/code/HEAD/tree/openflights/data/airports.dat?format=raw

The blog also provides the Python script to perform the insertion, though you could easily insert via a LOAD CSV Cypher script (I suggest adding headers that match the insertion below first; e.g. airportId, airportName, airportCity, etc.):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/airports.dat" AS line
CREATE (airport:Airport { id: line.airportId, name: line.airportName, city: line.airportCity, country: line.airportCountry, iata: line.airportIATA, icao: airportICAO, latitude: line.airportLat, longitude: line.airportLon, altitude: line.airportAltitude, offset: line.airportOffset, dst: line.airportDST, timezone: line.airportTimezone });
```

More information about the contents of the dataset is available here:

http://openflights.org/data.html

The blog posting above also then provides details on querying via Cypher, Java, etc.

If I come across any others, I'll update my answer.

**EDIT 1**
The dataset is not terribly big (less than 10,000 nodes), so you likely don't need the USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 or you can lower that number significantly if you wanted to keep it.

Also, this dataset is just nodes, and doesn't have any relationships.

You could certainly create relationships though, such as instead of inserting the country name into the airport node, you could create a country node and then relate the airport nodes to their associated country node:

Don't quote me on this (it may well be syntactically incorrect and/or not the best way to do this in Neo4j, but should give you a start) as I am still very new to Cypher, but I think it would go something like:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/airports.dat" AS line
CREATE (airport:Airport { id: line.airportId, name: line.airportName, city: line.airportCity, iata: line.airportIATA, icao: airportICAO, latitude: line.airportLat, longitude: line.airportLon, altitude: line.airportAltitude, offset: line.airportOffset, dst: line.airportDST, timezone: line.airportTimezone })
WITH airport, MERGE (country:Country { name: line.airportCountry })
ON CREATE SET (airport)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(country)
ON MATCH SET (airport)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(country);
```

**EDIT 2**
Additionally, check out:

http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/01/31/neo4j-spatial-part-1/

Specifically the reference to the restaurant data you can implement.

Comment: The airports dataset doesn't fit my needs. Though I could add some relationships as you suggested, this would create a bunch of clusters instead of one, big, connected graph that could instead be used for path-finding performance tests.
Anyway Neo4j Spatial is an interesting project I didn't know and I'll keep an eye on it =)